# android - TabLayout dynamically resize

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a TabLayout in my app and it holds custom views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.myproject.app.utils.commons.IconImageView
            android:id="@android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            app:iconStateListColor="@color/color_order_tab"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/color_order_tab"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to show text on the Tab only if it selected - already done - and resize these tabs dynamically, is there any way to do that?
If I use `app:tabMode="fixed"` tabs don't resize, if I use `app:tabMode="scrollable"` my tabs are always on the left of my screen. If I do  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` - TabLayout doesn't fill the screen..
So I need to:

- Resize tabs when text appears or disappears;
- Tabs should fill the screen in any case.

Comment: how did you hide text when unselected using this  app:tabSelectedTextColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: No, I hide text with setting text = "", empty string.

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you cannot obtain all the desired feature on using `fixed` mode. As in `fixed` mode, you cannot resize your tabs.
You need to use `scrollable` mode in order to resize the tabs.

> If I do android:layout_width="wrap_content" and
>   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" - TabLayout doesn't fill
>   the screen

You can set a parent container and set a background so that it gives you a feel of a tab layout with full device width.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then, you can add the tabs i.e. your custom tabs in your tab layout and after that, you can add `addOnTabSelectedListener` to get the desired results:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("large text one");

        View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        ((TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("1");

        View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        ((TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Large Text Text Text");

        View view3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        ((TextView) view3.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("One");


        View view4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        ((TextView) view4.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Another large text");

        mBinding.tabs.addTab(mBinding.tabs.newTab().setCustomView(view));
        mBinding.tabs.addTab(mBinding.tabs.newTab().setCustomView(view1));
        mBinding.tabs.addTab(mBinding.tabs.newTab().setCustomView(view2));
        mBinding.tabs.addTab(mBinding.tabs.newTab().setCustomView(view3));
        mBinding.tabs.addTab(mBinding.tabs.newTab().setCustomView(view4));

        mBinding.tabs.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mBinding.tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }
```

As you can see the tabs are now resizable and only text on the selected tab is visible. Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextAppearance="?attr/tabTextAppearance"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```